# How many accounts are affected by the vBulletin breach? At risk?

Tags: intrusion, zero-day

vBulletin hack(s) have affected vBulletin, itself (security questions and answers, salts, and hashes of more than 300,000 users of the 345k known to be registered), and Foxit Software (some data for 260k users -- but 535k are known to be registered).  Coldzer0 [Coldroot in some reports], has claimed responsibility and said that he had data for 479,895 users from vBulletin and Foxit obtained at least in part through an unknown (zero day) exploit.

A news report claims that over 100,000 forums use vBulletin.

How many accounts are likely compromised?  How many at risk?
How will other forums  determine whether they were breached?

Comment: I'm not sure how we would know this information.